# Assembly differences between unrolled for-loops cause differing float results

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-optimization, floating-accuracy, powerpc

Consider the below setup:

```
typedef struct
{
    float d;
} InnerStruct;

typedef struct
{
    InnerStruct **c;
} OuterStruct;


float TestFunc(OuterStruct *b)
{
    float a = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        a += b->c[i]->d;
    return a;
}
```

The for loop in TestFunc exactly replicates one in another function that I'm testing.
Both loops are unrolled by gcc (4.9.2) but yield slightly different assembly after doing so.

Assembly for my test loop:ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤAssembly for the original loop:

```
lwz       r9,-0x725C(r13)                   lwz       r9,0x4(r3)    
lwz       r8,0x4(r9)                        lwz       r8,0x8(r9)    
lwz       r10,0x0(r9)                       lwz       r10,0x4(r9)   
lwz       r11,0x8(r9)                       lwz       r11,0x0C(r9)  
lwz       r4,0x4(r8)                        lwz       r3,0x4(r8)    
lwz       r10,0x4(r10)                      lwz       r10,0x4(r10)  
lwz       r8,0x4(r11)                       lwz       r0,0x4(r11)   
lwz       r11,0x0C(r9)                      lwz       r11,0x10(r9)  
efsadd    r4,r4,r10                         efsadd    r3,r3,r10
lwz       r10,0x10(r9)                      lwz       r8,0x14(r9)   
lwz       r7,0x4(r11)                       lwz       r10,0x4(r11)  
lwz       r11,0x14(r9)                      lwz       r11,0x18(r9)  
efsadd    r4,r4,r8                          efsadd    r3,r3,r0
lwz       r8,0x4(r10)                       lwz       r0,0x4(r8)    
lwz       r10,0x4(r11)                      lwz       r8,0x0(r9)    
lwz       r11,0x18(r9)                      lwz       r11,0x4(r11)  
efsadd    r4,r4,r7                          efsadd    r3,r3,r10
lwz       r9,0x1C(r9)                       lwz       r10,0x1C(r9)  
lwz       r11,0x4(r11)                      lwz       r9,0x4(r8)    
lwz       r9,0x4(r9)                        efsadd    r3,r3,r0
efsadd    r4,r4,r8                          lwz       r0,0x4(r10)   
efsadd    r4,r4,r10                         efsadd    r3,r3,r11
efsadd    r4,r4,r11                         efsadd    r3,r3,r9
efsadd    r4,r4,r9                          efsadd    r3,r3,r0
```

The issue is the float values these instructions return are not exactly the same. And I can't change the original loop. I need to modify the test loop somehow to return the same values. I believe the test's assembly is equivalent to just adding each element one after another. I'm not very familiar with assembly so I wasn't sure how the above differences translated into c. I know this is the issue because if I add a print to the loops, they don't unroll and the results match exactly as expected.

Comment: What are some examples of the different results you get? If the differences are close to the precision that a float can represent I don't think you should be relying on getting the exact same result under any conditions.

Comment: Floating point is inherently inaccurate, and different ways of compiling the code can result in slightly different inaccuracies.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including source code and compile commands that produce the assembly code.

Comment: `c[i]` is a pointer, so `b->c[i].d` shouldn't compile. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The order of the `efsadd` instructions will affect the outcome. But the optimizer won't necessarily do the adds in the same order for the original loop versus the test loop. You might be able to get the results to be the same by making sure that all the numbers have the same magnitude, and have exact floating point representations.  That assumes that as part of your testing, you can control the numbers that the original loop is adding.

Comment: Floating point is inherently inaccurate *with respect to either the decimal or real-number arithmetic that humans are accustomed to thinking in*, but within its own domain, it's perfectly accurate.  It's also supposed to be perfectly repeatable — i.e. checking for exact equality *can* be legitimate.  So when an exercise like this shows discrepancies, they're usually due to a mistake the programmer has made, or a bug in the compiler.  But we don't yet have enough information about this discrepancy to say which.  We need to see the "other function that's being replicated", and perhaps the input.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.  Better to fix what breaks when the result differs, because that is the bug.  Have you really "lost precision" rather than simply got a _different_ imprecise result?  Remembering that float has a finite precision of just six significant digits decimal.

Comment: Floating-point addition is *not* associative like math addition. So result can differ if order of operations differs. Snippet on left computes (left to right): `c[0].d + c[1].d + c[2].d + c[3].d + c[4].d + c[5].d + c[6].d + c[7].d`. Snippet on right computes: `c[1].d + c[2].d + c[3].d + c[4].d + c[5].d + c[6].d + c[0].d + c[7].d`. Try instructing the compiler to maintain strictest compliance with IEEE-754 (e.g. `-fp-model:strict` for Intel compiler). May help, but not guaranteed to help.

Comment: @njuffa Nice catch.  Since floating-point addition is not associative, it's usually wrong for a compiler to rearrange floating-point expressions based on associativity, which is what I was getting at when I said "due to... a bug in the compiler".  (Or, if the "other function that's being replicated" indeed requested that other order, then what we have here is "a mistake the programmer has made".)

Comment: @SteveSummit Various compilation switches typically allow re-association of floating-point expressions, and some compilers may even have one of those enabled by default. In particular, `-ffast-math` is to be avoided. Sadly, asker did not document the compilation switches used.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yea, I probably could have used a better word than "precision" in the question. I knew the number itself was not going to exactly match whatever the expected result is. But both functions should have the same imprecision in their result, meaning those numbers should match exactly. I believe @njuffa is on the right track with ```-fp-model:strict``` or ```-ffast-math```. If so, then the question will be how I would go about forcing the order of element additions. I'm unable to change compilation switches for this one test so I would have to find a purely code-based solution.

Comment: If the compiler has been given a switch saying it may rearrange floating-point operations, there is generally no feasible way to write source code to ensure a particular order of floating-point operations. We are still waiting for you to provide a [mre], including source code that reproduces the problem and compile commands that produce the assembly code shown.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's more of a conceptual problem than one tied to any specific code. I'm unable to share the exact source code that has these issues nor the compilation scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling fast-math seems to fix this issue. Thanks to @njuffa for the suggestion. I was hoping to be able to design the test function around this optimization, but it doesn't seem to be possible. At least I know what the issue is now. Appreciate everyone's help on the problem!

Answer (score 2):

I presume this is for unit-testing the one function with another.

In general floating point calculations are never exact in C or C++ and it is [not usually considered](https://pvs-studio.com/en/docs/warnings/v2550/) legitimate to expect them to be.

The Java language standard requires exact floating point results.  Doing this is a constant source of [hatred against Java](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/JAVAhurt.pdf), with various accusations that making the results reproducible usually makes them less accurate and sometimes makes the code much slower too.

If you are doing your testing in C or C++ then I would suggest this approach:

Calculate the result as best you can, with both high precision and high accuracy.  In this case the input data are in 32-bit float, so convert them all to 64-bit float before calculating the expected result.

If the inputs were in double (and you don't have a bigger long double type) then sort the values into order and add them up smallest to largest.  This will result in the least loss of accuracy.

Once you have your expected result then test that the function output matches it within some bounds.

There are two approaches to setting what accuracy you require to consider the test as a pass:

One approach is to check what the real physical meaning of the number is and what accuracy you actually require.

The other approach is to just require that the result is accurate to within a few least-significant-bits of the ideal result, ie: that the error is less than a few times the ideal result times FLT_EPSILON.

Comment: True, the calculation will cause imprecision compared to the expected result. But as @SteveSummit said, shouldn't the imprecision in both functions be the same? If they're both run under the same compilation switches, I would expect them to always yield identical results. Those results are both imprecise compared to the expected result, yes, but compared to each other they should remain exactly equal. I'm already testing floats within certain bounds (±0.001) and 22% of tests are failing due to the discrepancy between the 2 loops.

Comment: Basically what you are suggesting is true in Java but not true in C or C++.  The reason is that in C/C++ the compiler is allowed to propagate intermediates with **more** precision that the type provides, and does not have to do so consistently.  Java requires that the extra precision be discarded after every operation, which many people say is stupid, but at least would give the kind of determinism you are hoping for.

Comment: If that's true, why does disabling fast-math fix the issue?

Comment: That's the nature of something not being guaranteed to be exact.  It can be the same any time it wants, it just doesn't have to be.  I'll still upvote your answer though, since that is the solution you wanted in this case.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding. I've ran a test of 10,000 random float values for d. With fast-math, we get those varying order of additions and roughly 30% of those tests fall outside of the acceptable range of ±0.001. But with fast-math disabled, every difference calculates to be exactly 0 and all 10,000 tests pass. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes.  You are missing the fact that the compiler is allowed to make what you have observed be the case, and it is also allowed to do differently, if what it does different is more accurate.  If you compile this code (with or without fast math) for a processor which has hardware support for double but not float, or where double is no slower than float, it could decide to do everything in double - then then the answer would not exactly match the value that you calculate in float.

Comment: Fortunately, this is only being run on a single processor where I get the expected result. So it looks like this solution is sufficient in this case. I appreciate the help and info!